# How to make the perl regex not to be greedy?

Tags: perl

I'm have paths like:

```
/nfs/usr/x86-64_linux71/gnua/4.0.0/features/com.asas.gnua.feature_4.0.0
/nfs/usr/x86-64_linux71/gnua/4.0.0/plugins/org.codehaus.jackson_1.0.0/META-INF
/nfs/usr/x86-64_linux71/gnua/4.0.0/configuration
/nfs/usr/x86-64_linux71/gnua/4.0.0/plugins/org.easymock_2.5.1
/nfs/usr/x86-64_linux71/gnua/4.0.0/features/org.eclipse.e4.rcp_1.6.100.v20180611-0422
```

I want to build a regex to catch those paths so `gnua` is the first group and `4.0.0` is the second group. I tried:

```
^\/nfs\/.*?\/.*?\_linux\d+\/(.*)?\/(.*)?\/.*?
```

But I get `gnua/4.0.0` as first group and `features` as second group. How can I make the first group be `gnua` and the second group to be `4.0.0` in Perl? In other words, the last `.*?` should be `features/com.asas.gnua.feature_4.0.0`.

Comment: Maybe `[^/]+`? Be more picky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the question marks into the matching groups.

```
/^\/nfs\/.*?\/.*?\_linux\d+\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/.*?/
```

Changing the delimiter improves readability:

```
m{^/nfs/.*?/.*?_linux\d+/(.*?)/(.*?)/.*?}
```

But using `([^/]*)` is usually safer than `(.*?)`.

Answer (score 1):

As already was indicated by [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) the **question mark** should be moved inside capture group brackets.

For a convenience you can define a string holding regular expression (it would also allow to reuse it in other parts of the code if such situation arise).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# vim: ai ts=4 sw=4

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re = '/nfs/usr/x86-64_linux.*?/(.*?)/(.*?)/';

while( <DATA> ) {
    my @arr = ($1,$2) if /$re/;
    say join("\t",@arr);
}

__DATA__
/nfs/usr/x86-64_linux71/gnua/4.0.0/features/com.asas.gnua.feature_4.0.0
/nfs/usr/x86-64_linux71/gnua/4.0.0/plugins/org.codehaus.jackson_1.0.0/META-INF
/nfs/usr/x86-64_linux71/gnua/4.0.0/configuration
/nfs/usr/x86-64_linux71/gnua/4.0.0/plugins/org.easymock_2.5.1
/nfs/usr/x86-64_linux71/gnua/4.0.0/features/org.eclipse.e4.rcp_1.6.100.v20180611-0422
```

Output

```
gnua    4.0.0
gnua    4.0.0
gnua    4.0.0
gnua    4.0.0
gnua    4.0.0
```